# Score calculation in dictionary looking for improvement

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create an dictionary with names and points from a textfile called "score.txt".
The contents of the file is stuctured like this:

```
Anders Johansson 1
Karin Johansson 1
Anders Johansson 2
Eva Johansson 0
```

+ 2000 names and points in total

My method of getting the scores, calculating and finding the high-score looks like this

```
f = open('score.txt').read().split()
d = {}
for x in range(0, len(f), 3):
    name, value = ' '.join([f[x], f[x+1]]), int(f[x+2])
    if(name in d):
        d[name] += value
    else:
        d[name] = value
print(max(d, key=d.get),d[max(d, key=d.get)])
```

I'm pretty new to python so i'm looking for ways to improve my code.

Comment: This question is pretty unambiguous. What are you after? Performance or code-style improvement? I'm afraid you will not get a "correct" answer for this question.

Comment: Check out [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This may be on-topic for Code Review, as long as **A** the code works **and B** it's not hypothetical or incomplete in anyway. Please read the on-topic guide before posting if you choose to go there.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You should know that these types of questions are considered off-topic here, mostly because there is no definite answer to your question, and most answers will only be of opinion about how your code should be styled. One thing I would like to point is that when you `.open()`, you got to `.close()`. Either that, or use the `with open('score.txt') as f: content = f.read()` syntax which will handle the closing automatically for you. Also, you may want to reconsider these 1 letter variable names. `f` I'd expect to hold the file object, not its content ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already looks non too crazy, but I have a few suggestions:

- Naming [Python convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is descriptive names (scores instead of d).
- [File opening](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) is best done with the `with` stanza.
- You can iterate over lines so you don't need the `range`.
- Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) so you don't need to test for existence in the dict.

That would yield:

```
from collections import defaultdict

scores = defaultdict(int)

with open('score.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split()
        name, score = ' '.join([fields[0], fields[1]]), int(fields[2])
        scores[name] += score

print(max(scores, key=scores.get), scores[max(scores, key=scores.get)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Small changes to your code. This will improve the performance a little .

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

datas ="""Anders Johansson 1
Karin Johansson 1
Anders Johansson 2
Eva Johansson 0""".split()

dic = defaultdict(int)

for i in range(0, len(f), 3):
    name, value = ' '.join([datas[i], datas[i+1]]), int(datas[i+2])
    dic[name] += value

max_key =max(dic, key=d.get)
print(max_key, dic[max_key])
```

**Output:**

```
('Anders Johansson', 3)
```

**Notes:**

- Since you are falling the same method with same parameter twice `max(d, key=d.get)` I have stored that in a variable and re-used it.
- Since the value of the dictionary is only int type I have used defaultdict

Answer (score 0):

The only semantic problem your code could present is that if you need to deal with [composite names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs), e.g., *Pablo Ruiz Picasso*. In this case the program will break. Also, if your file is large, for improving the performance would be better to compute the high score while reading the file. My concerns are handled in the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

highScore = 0
highScoreName = ""
scores = defaultdict(int)

with open('score.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       fields = line.split()
       name, score = ' '.join(fields[:-1]), int(fields[-1]) #Handle composite names
       scores[name] += score
       if scores[name] > highScore: #Compute high score
          highScore, highScoreName = scores[name], name

print highScoreName, highScore
```